# PHP HTML Decode

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

I'm forced to work with HTML that looks like this:

```
<font color=3D=22=236EAED2=22 style=3D=22font-siz=
e:13px;font-family:arial;=22><B>Some Info Here</B></font></=
A></td></tr><tr><td><font color=3D=22=23FFFFFF=22 style=3D=22font-size:11=
px;font-family:arial;=22>192 Wellington Parade =7C Melbourne =7C  VIC =7C=
Australia 3002</font></td></tr><tr><td><font color=3D=22=23FFFFFF=22 st=
yle=3D=22font-size:11px;font-family:arial;=22>T: 61-<a href=3D=22=23=22 s=
tyle=3D=22color:=23FFFFFF; text-decoration:none=22>
```

It looks like " gets converted to =22 and so on.
There is also other "codes" like =7C =3D, = before every new line and so on.

```
&nbsp; is =26nbsp;
```

Is there any function or technique for restoring to proper HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't belong in the PHP section.

Comment: It could, you can use str_replace to do some tinkering.

Comment: Yea well you can also use preg_replace not the point. I think php is out of the question here.

Comment: Not really @Daan - [Quoted Printable Decode](http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `quoted_printable_decode("YOUR String to decode");` OR `imap_qprint("Your String to decode")`

Check **[FIDDLE](http://codepad.org/U2VI58DN)**

Description : quoted_printable_decode — Convert a quoted-printable string to an 8 bit string

his function returns an 8-bit binary string corresponding to the decoded quoted printable string (according to » RFC2045, section 6.7, not » RFC2821, section 4.5.2, so additional periods are not stripped from the beginning of line).

[More Info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) and [here too](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! quoted_printable_decode() solved it pefectly, I had no idea about that function and @Gumbo your answer is also very helpfull, thank you.

Comment: @tonirmc , welcome . Both are same but  `imap_qprint()` :  this one requires the IMAP module/extension to work.

Answer (score 3):

That’s the [quoted-printable encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7), which can be decoded with [`quoted_printable_decode`](http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode).

Like so:

```
$input= "the string that you need to be decoded";
$output = quoted_printable_decode($input);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Links are perishable, you should include some code in your answer ;)

Comment: @AresDraguna Like `$output = quoted_printable_decode($input)` or what?

Comment: yes, exactly like that ;) again, links are perishable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're simply replacing '%' with =. You say that =22 gets translated into '"', and %22 is the url encoding character for ".

Look [here for a chart](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), and you can probably figure out a way to replace the characters with PHP.

Also, [quotedprintable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) and [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) could be of some use